# How did they figure out asteroid's dark side's composition in Armageddon?

Tags: movie, technology, armageddon

In the movie Armageddon, after the shuttles crash on the asteroid, Rockhound (Steve Buscemi's character) reveals that they overshot their planned landing site by 26 miles and that the current landing site is composed of metal while the planned landing site was composed of more easily drillable rocks.

But how did the nasa folks find the exact composition of different sections on the dark side of the asteroid (facing away from earth) of the asteroid? (Remember that the shuttles went around the moon so that they could land on the back of the asteroid). It wasn't emitting any radiation, wasn't rotating and they had not sent any exploratory probes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was tumbling (gently) before it came near to the moon, then it began toppling more erratically.

> “Before the asteroid passed the moon, her rotation was stable at
> thirty-two degrees on an X axis,” a NASA tech pointed out. “But now
> look—the lunar gravity’s put her in a spin. She’s rolling on all three
> axes. This wasn’t expected, sir—”
>
> <sub><sup>[Armageddon - The Novel](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/586707.Armageddon)</sup></sub>

NASA evidently snapped pictures of the asteroid from the ground (and using space-based telescopes), then used their enormous brains to guess what the composition was, based on infra-red imaging.

> Meanwhile, in the Mission Control asteroid-monitoring hub, Truman,
> Rockhound, Oscar, and Grace were busy studying printouts of the
> asteroid’s surface. **“Based on the thermographic imaging,” Rock-hound
> said, “Segment 201, Lateral Grid Six, site 12J14 that’s one prime
> landing site. Site 12G17’s another.”**

Answer (score 4):

In-movie they had maps and scans

[image]

Rockhound says:

> The reason we were shooting for Grid 8 is that **thermographics** indicated that Grid 9 was compressed iron ferrite.
>
> <sup>*Armageddon (1998)*</sup>

The script (which was much different from the final movie) is pretty silent except:

> A rogue comet came from deep space and collided with an  asteroid. Some  kids actually got a picture of the collision event and told no one.

Any space collision is almost certain to impart a rotation to the objects in question so although, perhaps, we don't *see* an obvious rotation it doesn't mean there wasn't one.